# Is this a valid approach to updating

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I had a long form which includes multiple combo boxes and textboxes.

I am using this form for registration, also I'm using same kind of form for updating.

1. I finished up the registration process using `INSERT` query.
2. For updates, I had one idea. **Instead of using `UPDATE` query, should I remove (`DELETE`) the record first and then insert it again into the database**, because since I already done the insertion process at first for registration, I can reuse the code.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 2):

There are scenarios (especially in bulk data movement jobs etc) where doing something like this might make sense.

But in your scenario, i really dont see any reason why you should do what you are suggesting.

There is no benefit that i can see from your approach other than saving you only a negligible amount of development time. On the cons, you application will execute 2 SQL statements (DELETE + INSERT) instead of 1 UPDATE everytime your user data gets updated.  Depending on how your application works, you will also additionally need some other logic to keep track of changes to users profiles as things like dtCreated etc will not suffice.

I would just go with a simple UPDATE statement instead.

Comment: That depends on how you are storing the id's. As long as the ID is not an auto_increment column, i dont see why you shouldnt be able to.

Comment: if i use DELETE+INSERT approach, how can i get the same id. thinks its a problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REPLACE INTO` command which uses the same syntax. Behind the screen it will perform a `DELETE` then an `INSERT`. If you use `InnoDB` tables and you have set up relations this can be very dangerous if you come to think that the `REPLACE INTO` will work like `UPDATE`. Result, bunch of **deleted rows** due to cascading rules.

You consider using `DELETE` followed by `INSERT` for updates because you have the insert-sql ready. Well you could use the `UPDATE` like syntax for inserts. That way it is just a matter of using INSERT/UPDATE according to your task.

So instead of:

```
INSERT INTO products (name) VALUES ('iPhone');
```

.. you would use:

```
INSERT INTO products SET name='iPhone';
```

Which looks much the same as the update:

```
UPDATE products SET name='iPhone' WHERE id=1;
```

Almost the same.